# Sort a DataFrame by sidetable subtotal

Tags: pandas, dataframe, subtotal

Input:
[Input DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9H0f.png)

I then obtained another df:

```
recap_table = df.groupby(['Cofor - Expéditeur',"Libellé de l'écart quantité - Ordre"]).agg(agg_func_count).stb.subtotal()
```

It looks like this:
[Subset Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8zxW.png)

i would like to be able to sort this new data frame by the 'subtotal' row. Is there a way to do so?

I expect an output where the recap dataframe is sorted by the subtotal value.

Comment: @jezrael, yes the function subtotal() is part of sidetable. It adds the 'Subtotal' row in my dataframe. But now I need to sort the IDs on the left through this subtotal value. Thank you!

Comment: Please add Input/Output Data for understanding.